# TypeError when class has static member `name`

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following TypeScript class

```
module Test {
    "use strict";

    class Foo {
        public static name = "foo";
    }
}
```

Pretty simple.

But when run in Chrome I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function Foo() { }'

Here's the generated javascript:

```js
var Test;
(function (Test) {
  "use strict";
  var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.name = "foo";
    return Foo;
  }());
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

If I use a different name then `name` I don't get an error.

```
module Test {
    "use strict";

    class Foo {
        public static huh = "foo";
    }
}
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to write to `Function.name`. In the code that you wrote initially, you can see in the compiled code that you are changing `Foo.name`.

Consider just this code

```
  function Foo(){}
  console.log(Foo.name); // prints 'Foo'
```

The error is because you are trying to change this function's property, and are not allowed to do so (`read-only property ..`). More information about why (and how) you are not allowed to do so can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). Thanks to @ssube for providing this link in the comments

So whilst you have not created that property yourself, all your functions do actually have it. You can check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) for some more information.

Comment: @Snæbjørn it's always nice when things make sense ^^ If this answers your question sufficiently, consider marking it as "accepted answer" to let other people with a similar question know :-)

Comment: You'll have to wait for the grace periode to expire

Comment: "are not allowed to do so" because of the magical (and little-known) property descriptors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description

Comment: @ssube Thanks, I have added this to the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is `Foo.name = "foo";` because *name* is a predefined property of functions in javascript (like *arguments*, *length* and such), which holds the name of the function ('Foo' in your case) so you can't overwrite it with your own definition

have a look on [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) for details

Comment: You can overwrite most predefined properties (it's actually a common problem when using generic names). This particular property is defined to not be writable.

Comment: true ... but it is configurable, so this will actually change the name `Object.defineProperty(Foo, 'name', {value: 'foo', configurable: true});`